# Update Mercurial installation on Mac OS X

Tags: mercurial, installation

How do I update my Mercurial installation from within Mercurial?

Or, if that's not possible, can I just download the newest installation package and overwrite the existing older version?

Comment: As Mercurial is a programming tool, I think this question fits better on SO then super user.

Comment: @Ian, this is actually on SO `:)`

Comment: but there is someone trying to close the quesion saying it should be on super user.  I am just pointer out to other 3k+ users that it should be on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to update Mercurial from within itself.

To update Mercurial I just download newest installation package and reinstall from it. Make sure you download one for your version of OS X (due to different python versions in different Mac OS X versions).